# AttributeError: 'Values' object has no attribute 'tab_width' when running sphinx-build

Tags: python, python-sphinx

When running:

```sh
sphinx-build -M html . _build
```

I get the following error:

```
Running Sphinx v3.0.3
building [mo]: targets for 0 po files that are out of date
building [html]: targets for 9 source files that are out of date
updating environment: [new config] 9 added, 0 changed, 0 removed
/home/vinzee/.pyenv/versions/3.6.14/envs/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/recommonmark/parser.py:75: UserWarning: Container node skipped: type=document                                                      
  warn("Container node skipped: type={0}".format(mdnode.t))
reading sources... [ 66%] api                                                                                                                                                                                      
Exception occurred:
  File "/home/vinzee/.pyenv/versions/3.6.14/envs/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sphinx/ext/autodoc/__init__.py", line 440, in get_doc
    tab_width = self.directive.state.document.settings.tab_width
AttributeError: 'Values' object has no attribute 'tab_width'
The full traceback has been saved in /tmp/sphinx-err-tm3jn6xm.log, if you want to report the issue to the developers.
Please also report this if it was a user error, so that a better error message can be provided next time.
A bug report can be filed in the tracker at <https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues>. Thanks!
```

My versions:

```
Python: 3.6.14  
sphinx-build: 3.0.3
```

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pinning `docutils<=0.16` works.

I found the answer on the [Sphinx github repository](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/9049#issuecomment-812900558).

The error is found on all `docutils>0.16` versions.

Comment: The [bug is in recommonmark](https://github.com/readthedocs/recommonmark/issues/220), which is no longer maintained and is [deprecated in favor of MyST](https://github.com/readthedocs/recommonmark#recommonmark).